# Yii2:Passing variable to view having different Action

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2, session-variables

I have two actions in one controller `site` as below: Now I want to pass the variable `$count` from Action `check` to view file rendered by `actionDomain`

```
public function actionDomain()
    {

      $model = new DomainCheckerForm();
      return $this->render('domainChecker', [
            'model' => $model,

        ]);

    }
     public function actionCheck()

     {          
        $model = new DomainCheckerForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {          
        $session = Yii::$app->session;
        $session->open();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['count']))
        {
           $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
           $_SESSION['first'] = time();
        }
        else
        {
           // Increase the Count
           $_SESSION['count']++;
        }
$count=($_SESSION['count']);    
   // var_dump($count);exit;
```

I have tried multiple ways without any success like:

```
echo $this->render('domainChecker', [
    'count' => $count

]);
```

and

```
Yii::$app->runAction('domain', ['count'=>$count]);
```

But nothing seems to work.

update: `domainChecker.php` Content

```
<head>
<style>
.loader {
    text-align: center;    
}
.loader span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.9s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: loader 0.9s infinite alternate;
}
.loader span:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.loader span:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-21px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-21px);
  }
}
    </style>


<?php
$script = <<< JS
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.loader').hide();
$("#domain-check").submit(function (event) {

    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();


    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');

    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).serialize();
    $('.loader').show();
    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */

    $.ajax({
        url: "?r=site/check",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function (response) {
           $('.loader').hide();
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
});
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>


</head>



<?php


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model \frontend\models\ContactForm */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\captcha\Captcha;
//use yii\web\Session;



$this->title = 'Check Domain';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-contact">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        If you have business inquiries or other questions, please fill out the Contact form to contact us. Thank you.
    </p>

    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'domain-check','enableAjaxValidation'   => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => false,

        'fieldConfig' => [
            'options' => [
                'tag' => 'span',
            ],

        ],
    ]); ?>


              <?=  $form->field($model, 'domain',[
                  'template' =>
                  '<div class="input-group ">
                      {input}
                  {error}','inputOptions' => [
            'placeholder' => 'i.e. yourbusinessname.com',
            'class'=>'form-control',
        ]])
    ?>

               <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <input class="btn btn-success " value="Search" type="submit"></span></div>

                <?php


                echo $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
                    'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
                ]) ?>
 <?php echo $count; ?>


            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="loader">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div> 
<div id="result" class="row"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use return   instead of echo

```
return $this->render('domainChecker', [
    'count' => $count
]);
```

And  You can invoke an action from another action using

eg

```
 $this->redirect(array('your-controller/your-action', 'var1'=>$var1, 'var2'=>$var2));
```

In you case you should add the proper param the action definition

```
public function actionYourAction($var1, $var2)
{
     ..... 
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error `undefined variable count` when accessing the view file. When I am trying to access the variable as `echo $count` in view file.

Comment: Show the domainChecker.php views content

Comment: I have updated the question with the domainChekcer.php views content.

Comment: @Joshi   . i don't see $count in domainChekcer view  .. . please tell me where is  ..

Comment: it is just before `<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>`

Comment: It 'strange .. in your render is not present $ model but there is $ count, in the view using $ model and does not give you error and gives you the error for $ count .. you are sure that the code you posted for controller and view are the right ones

Comment: @scaisEgdge - I have put up exactly as it is my code.

Comment: `model` in present in render in `actionDomain` that is why there is no error for `model`

Comment: @Joshi   . the render  don't invoce the action but the view  .. so if you don't have the $model in render call how  you obtain the model ..?  .. which action are you invoking  .. show me the url?

Comment: In this way you are invoking the execution for actionDoman .. that don't assign $count .. otherwise  if you invoke the action  `http://localhost/hosting/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fcheck`  .. you have $count and not $model .. then  in both case if you want use the same view  you should check for the proper vars if are setted and if they are use them otherwise not ....  i have also update the answer with a brief suggestion  for test

Comment: That exactly is my question, how can pass the variable from one action to another. is it not possible?

Comment: I have update the code, but then I am getting what I set for `$domain` in `actionDomain` and not the value passed from `actionCheck`

Comment: I misunderstood your question .. I delete my answer.

Comment: It's Ok, No Problem.

Comment: @Joshi  . i have update the answer .. could be that you are looking for redirection ..

Comment: can we move to chat.

Comment: @Joshi  open the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127128/discussion-between-joshi-and-scaisedge).